# Stack completions in realizability toposes

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, stacks, realizability

An internal category $\mathbb A$ in an elementary topos $\mathcal E$ is called an **(intrinsic) stack** if the indexed category that it represents, $(X\in \mathcal E) \mapsto \mathcal{E}(X,\mathbb A) \in \rm Cat$, is a stack for the regular topology of $\mathcal E$.  An internal functor is called a **weak equivalence** if it is internally essentially surjective and fully faithful; this is strictly weaker than being an internal equivalence if the axiom of choice does not hold in $\mathcal{E}$.  However, if $f:\mathbb A \to \mathbb B$ is a weak equivalence and $\mathbb C$ is a stack, then the induced functor $\mathrm{Cat}(\mathcal E)(\mathbb B,\mathbb C)\to \mathrm{Cat}(\mathcal E)(\mathbb A,\mathbb C)$ is an equivalence.

Say that $\mathcal E$ satisfies the **axiom of stack completions (ASC)** if every internal category admits a weak equivalence to an internal category that is a stack (see Bunge and Hermida, "Pseudomonadicity and 2-stack completions").  If $\mathcal E$ is a Grothendieck topos, then stack completions can be constructed using the small object argument, as fibrant replacements in the model structure on $\mathrm{Cat}(\mathcal E)$ constructed by Joyal and Tierney ("Strong stacks and classifying spaces"), so it satisfies ASC.

My question is whether realizability toposes also satisfy ASC?

I suspect the answer is no, because realizability toposes can contain small categories that are [weakly complete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category), meaning that their stack completions are indexed-complete, but the last I heard it was unknown whether they can contain small categories that are strongly complete in the internal-category sense.  If they satisfied ASC then this distinction would not be an issue since stack completion could be applied to the original weakly complete internal category to produce a strongly complete one.  However, if this is the case, I would like to see a concrete example or proof that ASC does *not* hold in a realizability topos.